# Search and replace using DOM and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am trying to make a webpage that allows the user to enter in the filepath of a .txt file and then search for and replace strings in the .txt file. I have done a bit of searching and only found pages saying it can't be done because of security reasons and im pretty sure this is rubbish.

How do i do it?

Comment: You think it's rubbish that a browser can't modify files on your system?

Comment: -1 for calling an important security feature rubbish.

Answer (score 3):

It's not rubbish.  There is `FileReader`, but it's only supported by some browsers, and it only gives you read only access.  [Chrome evidently supports](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) a `FileWriter`, but you can only write to a sandboxed environment.

You need to upload the file to a server, do the modifications, then send the modified file back -- note this won't get rid of the original.

Comment: Wow... nice helpful response guys...

I was saying that the pages i found were saying there is no way to read files from your computer. Which I don't believe to be true since i have been on many websites that have done it before. I figured since i explained the goal it would clarify what i meant but obviously not.

I am attempting to do this locally only. Not for server use. I just need the page to load a .txt file, and search for and replace strings. Is my question still to vague?

Comment: its not too vague, its simply not possible.  the best you can do is it upload it to a server then download the replacement.  It's on purpose that the browser can't modify files itself.

Comment: I was given this for homework,. This is specifically what it asks for:

A text field to allow users to specify the address of a text file ended with .txt and a submit botton to load the text file into the current webpage (e.g., in a div section).
A text field to allow users to specify a string to be searched from the text file.
Two text fields to allow users to specify two strings and a submit button to confirm the replacement of the first string with the second string in the text file.
A reset button to reset the form and reset the styles of highlighted text in the text file.

Comment: @user1388345 - in browsers that support it, html5's [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader) (as mentioned by hvgotcodes) should let you do what you've just described, noting that you will not be able to write the results back to the filesystem.